# In Skylark - given Label - how to read the tags of the original rule

Tags: bazel

In my skylark (bazel) rule implementation, I have a depset of [File objects](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/File.html) from which I extract a depset of [Label Objects](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/Label.html).

In common attributes I found that all skylark rules may have [tags](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/common-definitions.html#common.tags) attribute, where I can give a list of free strings.

Is there any way I can reach the tags of the original rule?

(my final goal is to extract from the original depset the files that are originated from rule with tag "X").

Answer (score 2):

Rules propagate information downstream (to rules depending on them) via *[Providers](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/rules.html#providers)*. Providers are pieces of information (structs) that a rule can either return or not. I find it useful to view Providers as interfaces a rule can choose to implement. For example a Skylark rule that returns a `cc` provider can be viewed as if it implemented the C++ rule interface, so we can expect it to be a meaningful dependency of C++ rules and of any rule that happens to read `cc` providers. If the rule doesn't implement the `java` provider though, then we can't expect it to work as a java rule's dependency.

A rule can only access information in its direct dependencies, and only via Providers. Therefore to access the `tags` of a dependency, the dependency would have to expose a Provider with that information. AFAIK there's no such provider that a rule could expose, but if the dependent rules (whose `tags` you want to extract) are also Skylark rules and you can modify their implementation, then just return a custom provider with their `tags` in it and you're done.

If however you want to depend on native `*_test` rules for example (the ones typically using `tags`), you'll need to employ a wrapper.

The basic idea is to write a [Skylark macro](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/macros.html) to wrap such rules. Instead of writing e.g. `cc_test(..., tags=...)` in the BUILD file, you'd write `my_macro(..., tags=...)`.

The macro's implementation would instantiate two rules: the `native.cc_test` and a simple Skylark rule (that you have to implement) which only has a `tags` attribute and a single label attribute for the test rule. The macro passes the `tags` to both rules (plus the rest of the attributes to the `cc_test`), and the Skylark rule depends on the test rule so it has access to its depset of files, and can return a custom provider with the depset and the tags data within one struct.

Comment: Thanks!! So that means that if I depend on a native rule (like java_library) I cannot modify it's providers, and I cannot reach to its tags.

Comment: regarding getting information about indirect dependencies: It's not really documented anywhere but I see that rules_scala has chosen to add another field "extra_information": https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/master/scala/scala.bzl#L421 which collects extra_information field from all direct dependencies. Do you know if any other provided rule behaves this way?

Comment: > if I depend on a native rule (like java_library) I cannot modify it's providers, and I cannot reach to its tags.

Correct.

Comment: *which collects extra_information field from all direct dependencies. Do you know if any other provided rule behaves this way?* -- 

No, I don't think any native rule has such free-form extensible fields. Many native rules provide information pertaining to their entire transitive closure of course, like C++ rules' [`cc.transitive_files`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/CcSkylarkApiProvider.html) field. The key idea is that the rule can decide what information about its own deps does it provide downstream, as opposed to the parent sending a visitor object down the graph.